# How to check in bash script that it was started by "Run in Terminal" from GUI?

Tags: bash, gui

I run bash scripts. I want to run them both from terminal, and from GUI with "Run in Terminal" and leave after run interactive `bash`. [Simply seeing output is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446391/how-to-prevent-terminal-window-from-closing-when-linux-bash-script-terminates) : add `read -rn1`.

[Problem X](https://xyproblem.info/):
I want a "clean" solution, to have at the end same terminal with bash that I can close with one `exit` if script is run from terminal and if from GUI. I can add `bash -i`, but if run from terminal it would require two `exit` to close the terminal. `exec bash -i` resulted in same.

Is there a way in a script to check if it was started from GUI via "Run in Terminal"?

Added 1 per comment:

```
ps aux | grep aaaa # while script started from GUI was running
mint       53293  0.1  0.0  11216  3356 pts/3    Ss+  21:58   0:00 /bin/bash /home/mint/aaaaa.sh
```

Noted the difference from one started from terminal is `Ss+` instead of `S+`.

Comment: I suggest inspecting the output of ``env`` for extra environment variables that are being passed when run this way. Though I doubt that will yield a portable solution as DEs each tend to do their own thing.

Comment: Please start your `bash` script from the GUI, and ***while it is running*** start `ps aux | less` in another terminal window. Look through that list of processes, and find the line(s) that show the name of your script - or add a `grep` pipe onto the `ps` command above. Add that line(s) to your question.

Comment: @Seamus, added, noted difference - see at the end.

Comment: OK - I may have an answer for you in a few... any feedback appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your bash script is named `/path/to/mybashscript.sh`

Use `ps` to find `mybashscript.sh` (`$0` if run within the script); include the `state/stat` columns to identify the specific states:

```
ps --sort +pid -eo pid,stat,command | grep "$0" | head -1 | awk '{print $2}' | grep "s"
```

or another way to filter out `grep` line:

```
ps -eo pid,stat,command | grep "$0" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | grep "s"
```

From your comments the difference is due to added `s`: `s    is a session leader` for GUI way, Ubuntu does not have that way to start script from file manager to check.

From `man ps`, the state codes are as follows:

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
   Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display
   to describe the state of a process:

           D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
           I    Idle kernel thread
           R    running or runnable (on run queue)
           S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
           T    stopped by job control signal
           t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
           W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
           X    dead (should never be seen)
           Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent

   For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be displayed:

           <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
           N    low-priority (nice to other users)
           L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
           s    is a session leader
           l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
           +    is in the foreground process group
```

Comment: thanks but looks like you have not understood correctly ;-) I want less manual typing each time, even extra `exit` better be eliminated, but you advice to run do so much ;-) I want to add lines to the script so that it handled all by itself. But due to your comment about `ps aux` I've found out output differs. So I hope I can use it within the script to do what I wanted. If you update the answer to use `Ss` vs `S+` and hopefully explain what it means (cause I'd like to know as I'm curious), I think I'll gladly accept the answer.

Comment: @Martian2020: Glad to do that, but you'll have to explain what you're doing as I am still unclear on 2 things. First - is it `Ss` or `S+` that you are looking for? Second - are you planning on using the PID obtained by `ps` to kill the chosen process (`Ss` or `S+`) in a script?

Comment: as stated in the question: I use difference in output of ps within the script to find out how it was run. I doubt one can `kill` the script process and have both previous output and working bash after that in case of running from GUI.

Comment: to know what `Ss+` means is needed e.g. to access portability of the solution. Already added to the script: `ps aux | grep "$0" | grep 'Ss+' > /dev/null ; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then bash -i; fi` - not using `basename` is even better I think now.

Comment: `man ps` "s    is a session leader". And  "S    interruptible sleep" so S was accidental, but using `s` might be workable, still more complex filtering is needed.

Comment: OK - I can't test this on my system because I don't know how this `Run in Terminal` thing works - I cannot find it on my Ubuntu system. More complex filtering possible using `regex` with `grep` - but without being able to `Run in Terminal`, I can't help find the exact combination that's needed. Made the changes you requested earlier, but see you've already found `man ps` as the source for that

Comment: I double click on a script in file manager and it shows options. Current iteration: `ps --sort +pid -eo pid,stat,command | grep "$0" | head -1 | awk '{print $2}' | grep "s" > /dev/null` as script might have `grep` in the name, but additional `grep -v` reminded me to select only one line.

Comment: In Ubuntu's default file manager, a double-click on an executable script file opens it in an editor window. What is the name of yur file manager app in mint?

Comment: Nemo. I booted Ubuntu, found out it has on right-click Open in terminal for folders, but not files, it surprised me. couple of steps further I now try to understand why Linux Mint do not have Terminal in the menu, I had to add it to Desktop to find out it is `gnome-terminal`, but opening with `gnome-terminal` from Nemo just opens empty terminal, not runs the script. Lot of things to learn about the system.

Comment: Ubuntu does not have an option in file manager GUI to open with app not in the list at all.

Comment: Anyway I think my initial question is closed (I tested it a bit), we continue here out of desire to learn about the system (at least me). Wanna finalize the answer and end?

Comment: Yeah sure - do you want to take a shot at editing?